# How to unlock GT90 in Gran Turismo 2?

Tags: gran-turismo-2

How can I unlock the Ford GT90 in Gran Turismo 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to multiple websites, winning the Seattle Circuit 100 Miles Endurance Race will give a chance of unlocking the car. I can't confirm if this information is true, though.

Edit: [Another website](http://tagtag.com/pravada-ps1/g/gran_turismo_2) states that you need to unlock the Nissan R390 GT1 '97' Roadcar before winning the Seattle Circuit.

*(Note: Most of these answers are user submitted answers on other websites.)*